# Point dataset from CSV showing up outside of known region

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, csv

I'm using QGIS and trying to display point data from a CSV file.  I've added a vector layer with a shapefile of Canada.  Both the project CRS and the shapefile CRS are set to NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert.

The CSV file CRS is also set to NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert.

The points should appear somewhere in the province of Manitoba.  However, the points show up outside of the map.

As shown by the attribute table, the lat / long appears normal, but the points show up at the wrong location.

What I am doing wrong here?  I've tried to ensure that both CRS projections are the same.  I've also tried switching the x and y in the CSV import, but the points still continue to show up at the same location.

Here is the CSV file data:

```
-98.43936109999999,49.3958333,TCR1
-98.38749999999999,49.3505556,TCR2
-98.38666669999999,49.3630556,TCR3
-98.3791667,49.3277778,TCR4
-98.3697222,49.39777779999999,TCR5
-98.3605556,49.3361111,TCR6
-98.3363889,49.3902778,TCR7
-98.33138889999998,49.3844444,TCR8
```

[image: Point outside]

[image]

Comment: You may have set the CRS of your CSV to NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert, but you didn't actually change the coordinates so they're still in lat/lng WGS84.  You have assigned the incorrect CRS.  If you just want them to overlay visually, remove the CSV and re-add it and specify the CRS as WGS84 (or right click CSV layer - "Set CRS"). If you want to reproject, use the Reproject Layer tool (after assigning the correct CRS).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the provinces shapefile in to QGIS (Canlamb)

load the csv - but chose WGS84

Then when you select CRS by project it will move your points to Manitoba

Like in the screenshot (changed field names from your file)
[image]